# Where should I place the function?

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that prints the first 100 prime numbers and checks the number's digits.

I used 2 different functions (required by my homework assignment). The first one finds the first 100 prime numbers and the second checks the digits. The first one is working normally but the second one cannot check the digits. Here is my code. Where should I place the digit function?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int digit_founder(int numbers, int digit) {
  while (numbers > 0) {
    numbers = numbers / 10;
    digit++;
  }
}

int primelist(int i, int count, int numbers, int prime_count, int digit) {
  for (numbers = 2; prime_count < 100; numbers++) {
    count = 0;

    for (i = 2; i <= numbers / 2; i++) {
      if (numbers % i == 0) count++;
    }

    if (count == 0) {
      digit_founder(numbers, digit);
      printf(" %d - %d Digit\n", numbers, digit);
      prime_count++;
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  int i, count, numbers, prime_count = 0, digit = 0;
  primelist(i, count, numbers, prime_count, digit);

  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
 2 - 0 Digit
 3 - 0 Digit
 5 - 0 Digit
 7 - 0 Digit
 11 - 0 Digit
 13 - 0 Digit
 17 - 0 Digit
 19 - 0 Digit
 23 - 0 Digit
 29 - 0 Digit
 31 - 0 Digit
 37 - 0 Digit
 41 - 0 Digit
 43 - 0 Digit
 47 - 0 Digit
 53 - 0 Digit
 59 - 0 Digit
 61 - 0 Digit
 67 - 0 Digit
 71 - 0 Digit
 73 - 0 Digit
 79 - 0 Digit
 83 - 0 Digit
 89 - 0 Digit
 97 - 0 Digit
 101 - 0 Digit
 103 - 0 Digit
 107 - 0 Digit
 109 - 0 Digit
 113 - 0 Digit
 127 - 0 Digit
 131 - 0 Digit
 137 - 0 Digit
 139 - 0 Digit
 149 - 0 Digit
 151 - 0 Digit
 157 - 0 Digit
 163 - 0 Digit
 167 - 0 Digit
 173 - 0 Digit
 179 - 0 Digit
 181 - 0 Digit
 191 - 0 Digit
 193 - 0 Digit
 197 - 0 Digit
 199 - 0 Digit
 211 - 0 Digit
 223 - 0 Digit
 227 - 0 Digit
 229 - 0 Digit
 233 - 0 Digit
 239 - 0 Digit
 241 - 0 Digit
 251 - 0 Digit
 257 - 0 Digit
 263 - 0 Digit
 269 - 0 Digit
 271 - 0 Digit
 277 - 0 Digit
 281 - 0 Digit
 283 - 0 Digit
 293 - 0 Digit
 307 - 0 Digit
 311 - 0 Digit
 313 - 0 Digit
 317 - 0 Digit
 331 - 0 Digit
 337 - 0 Digit
 347 - 0 Digit
 349 - 0 Digit
 353 - 0 Digit
 359 - 0 Digit
 367 - 0 Digit
 373 - 0 Digit
 379 - 0 Digit
 383 - 0 Digit
 389 - 0 Digit
 397 - 0 Digit
 401 - 0 Digit
 409 - 0 Digit
 419 - 0 Digit
 421 - 0 Digit
 431 - 0 Digit
 433 - 0 Digit
 439 - 0 Digit
 443 - 0 Digit
 449 - 0 Digit
 457 - 0 Digit
 461 - 0 Digit
 463 - 0 Digit
 467 - 0 Digit
 479 - 0 Digit
 487 - 0 Digit
 491 - 0 Digit
 499 - 0 Digit
 503 - 0 Digit
 509 - 0 Digit
 521 - 0 Digit
 523 - 0 Digit
 541 - 0 Digit

--------------------------------
Process exited after 0.04263 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: You're missing a `return` statement in the function `digit_founder()` and (unrelated) in `primelist()` too. **Suggestion: turn on all the warnings your compiler can emit, mind those warnings**.

Comment: You accomplish what prng suggests using flags like `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`, but check your compiler documentation to be sure.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that when function `digit_fouder()` modifies its parameter `digit`, the corresponding argument in its caller will reflect the change.  This is not the case.  In C, all arguments are passed by value, meaning that the function's parameters get independent copies of the values presented by the caller.  However, you have that `return` statement you need to add, so why not do the conventional thing and use that to return the computed result?

Comment: You also need to initialize digit to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is you are [passing by the value](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/pass-by-value-vs-pass-by-reference). That means, the `digit_founder` has a copy of the variable you have used in the `primelist` function (here `digit`). Whatever changes you make inside `digit_founder` won't make any change to the variable `digit` in in `primelist`.

To get the value from `digit_founder` you have to either return the result or should pass from `primelist` it as a pointer.

```
int digit_founder(int numbers, int digit) {
  digit = 0
  while (numbers > 0) {
    numbers = numbers / 10;
    digit++;
  }
 return digit;
}
```

Return the `digits` back to the callee. As mentioned in comments also initialize `digit` to 0.

```
if (count == 0) {
  digit = digit_founder(numbers, digit);
  printf(" %d - %d Digit\n", numbers, digit);
  prime_count++;
}
```